# how can I change /var permissions back?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-permissions

I gave a 0777 permissions to /var (I didn't know back then that it's a really bad thing to do)
I did this while in /var :

```
chmod -R 0777 *
```

after I did this postgresql fails to restart everytime.
my question is, how can I return the whole /var permission tree to its default status ?

Comment: Uh...restore from backup?

Comment: Restore from your latest backup. If you don't want to overwrite data, check your permissions on your backup media and write a shell script to set the permissions on your disk according to what you have on your backups.

Answer (score 2):

You should solve this issue by restoring your system from a backup that was taken before you did this.